# Dynamic Calculations in Text Boxes?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm fairly new to PHP and trying to build a dynamic part to an email form where there are two textboxes side by side. The first one is quantity and the second is total.

I'd like for it to multiply the first textbox by a set value of 15 and then display the result of this in the second total textbox which will be read only.

Any suggestions as to how I'd go about this? I've been scouring the web for ages trying to find help but I can't seem to find any.

My existing form code is this:

```
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" class="t4">
    <tr>
      <td width="48">Code</td>
      <td width="196">Event</td>
      <td width="56">Cost</td>
      <td width="66">Number</td>
      <td width="72">£ Total</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Lifewriting Workshop</td>
      <td>£15</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Number-of-Tickets" id="W1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="Total" id="W1"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you show the code that you have already written?

Comment: Its javascript not php you want for this

Comment: Thanks! I've added in part of the contact form.

Comment: Do you have anything more than html?

Comment: @user2482397 Unfortunately PHP runs once when you fetch the page. You can't do anything dynamic with it without Javascript, which runs in the browser.

Comment: I notice both your input boxes have the same `id="W1"`. This will cause a problem. They need to have unique IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/G8vMd/5/)

Just a simple demo,nothing fancy.This is in jquery,but I guess logic is what we want.

```
$('input').on("keyup",function () {
    $("#result").val(parseInt($("#amount").val(), 10)*  15);
});
```

Comment: @user2482397:I hope you are ok with jquery,just asking since it wasnt tagged!!!feel free to ask if you dont understand some part,its pretty simple anyways!!

Comment: Thanks! I've copied the code exactly as is in jsFiddle with Jquery included. For some reason it isn't working. Might it be because I've a number of other input elements too on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

using javascript you can do the following

```
 var text1 = document.getElementById('textbox1').value;
 document.getElementById('textbox2').value = parseInt(text1) * 15; //can use parseFloat() if you have floating point numbers
```

The first textbox your enter the quantity should have an `id` called `textbox1` as

```
<input type='text' id='textbox1' ...
```

The second textbox should have an id `textbox2`. You can have any id you like as long as you put the respective id in javascript code for reference.

Further more you need to trigger this code from a function which is called by `onkeydown` event or `onchange` event. On change event you will notice the change once after you enter the numbers and take the focus out of your `textbox` to call events you can trigger them using the event attributes of an element.

```
<input type='text' id='textbox1' onkeydown='somejavascriptfunc()`
```

This solution uses pure javascript code, the answer from MESSIAH uses a library called `jquery` which makes your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side language so in order to do some calculation you need to send a request to server. You can do this in PHP by making a desired form, sending entered value to the server and generating the page again but with readonly field populated by the result. Better way is to use javascript for this as the calculation is really simple and there is no need for it to be run on server. Search for javascript event listeners and look at jQuery which has easy to use functions for retrieving values from fields and handling events.